# How to create every permutation of a character set in every order -Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python (just started yesterday), and I'm trying to create permutations of a character set e.g. ascii_lowercase for use in a crypto program. I'm currently using the following:

```
...function definitions etc
while i <= num:
  for k in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(charset, i):
    nhash = str(''.join(k))
    fp.write(nhash + '\n')
    ...hashing code and other file I/O
  i += 1
```

given a character set of 'abc' it will give:

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
bb
...etc
```

It managed to correctly hit 'aa'; however, it missed 'ba' and for a cryptographic hashing algorithm ab != ba. Essentially I would like to find an itertools.permutations_with_replacement function.

Is there any way to get both ba and bb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you need [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) rather than [itertools.combinations_with_replacement](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

And here is the implementation with itertools.product

```
charset='ABC'
print '\n'.join(''.join(p) for i in xrange(1,len(charset)+1) 
                for p in itertools.product(charset, repeat=i))

A
B
C
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
```

Note if you need to use the value rather than to print it you can always use the generator

```
for x in (''.join(p) for i in xrange(1,len(charset)+1) 
                for p in itertools.product(charset, repeat=i)):
    print x
    ...hashing code and other file I/O
```